# fuze template for angular chat not refreshing Conversation after using websocket

Tags: c#, angular, websocket

I have chat service in angular which updating new incoming chats with websocket real time updating (works great) so I am getting from the websocket the message and phone number and send it to update my chat

```
 updateChatMessages(phoneNumber: string, message: string) {
      const chats = this._chats.value;
      const chatIndex = chats.findIndex((chat) => chat.phoneNumber === phoneNumber);
    
      if (chatIndex > -1) {
        const newChat = { ...chats[chatIndex] };
        // Generate a unique message ID (for example, using a timestamp)
        const messageId = new Date().getTime().toString();
    
        newChat.messages.push({
          id: messageId,
          chatId: newChat.id,
          contactId: newChat.contactId,
          isMine: false,
          value: message,
          createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
          isRead: false,
        });
    
        // Update the chat in the list of chats
        chats[chatIndex] = newChat;
    
        // Update the _chats BehaviorSubject with the updated list of chats
        this._chats.next([...chats]);
    
        // Update the _chat BehaviorSubject if the updated chat is the one being observed
        if (this._chat.value && this._chat.value.phoneNumber === phoneNumber) {
          this._chat.next(newChat);
        }
      }
    }
```

the issue I have that its not refreshing the dom in the ConversationComponent that is the open conversation, and I wish if I have list of chats it will show me notification that new messages coming.

```
this._chatService.chat$
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
            .subscribe((chat: Chat) => {
                this.chat = chat;

                // Mark for check
                this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
            });
```

but I cant use ChangeDetectorRef because its in a service and BehaviorSubjects and will cause a cycle. how can I make sure its refreshing the dom?
I USED THIS https://angular-material.fusetheme.com/apps/chat/ff6bc7f1-449a-4419-af62-b89ce6cae0aa

Answer (score 0):

You say that you cannot use _changeDetectorRef because it is in a service, but the snippet that you show that utilizes _changeDetectorRef looks like it would be in the component, not the service.

So you should be able to subscribe to the chat$ observable and then when a new value is emitted you should be able to call _changeDetectorRef.markForCheck() just as you have shown.